# Facing Problem with latest Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 with React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, android-studio

I have download latest Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 with React Native but after running React Native Project Emulator not launching giving me this error
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: The emulator (INFO    | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\Yogesh\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.1.19.db, detection is enabled for process: 5940) quit before it finished opening. You can try starting the emulator manually from the terminal with: C:\Users\Yogesh\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/emulator/emulator @INFO    | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\Yogesh\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.1.19.db, detection is enabled for process: 5940.

And There is another issue in Android Studio After rebuild android project giving me this error
Unable to make progress running work. There are items queued for execution but none of them can be started
And not able upgrade AGP version

I am trying to run React Native Application but emulator not launching

Answer (score 0):

same issue, resolved with following this

https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/1801#issuecomment-1980580355

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: There is another issue in Android Studio After rebuild android project giving me this error Unable to make progress running work. There are items queued for execution but none of them can be started And not able upgrade AGP version